# The position of the button in the toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I need to place the button to the left of the text (Learn). How do I do that?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_back"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  you want to create a back button. For that you dont have create icon and set it. Android gives default function for that.

in on create you have to add

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

and out of on create add this

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Toolbar by removing the default toolbar and setting the activity's theme to NoActionBar.

Now just place both the ImageButton ic_menu_send and the TextView "learn" inside the Toolbar layout as below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.joelkingsleyr.toolbartest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="learn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Also, set the activity's theme in the manifest file to AppTheme.NoActionBar